# Invoke API async stopped working - Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, api, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

Some days ago I implemented custom authentication for Azure Mobile Services. Everything worked back there. Surprisly it looks like it stopped working, although I have not changed a single line!

Here is the response from the API:

```
response.send(200, {
                UserID: userId,
                Token: jwthelper.zumoJwt(aud, userId, masterKey),
                Status: "SUCCESS",
                Name: account.name,
                Email: account.email
});
```

And here my call:

```
var userCredentials = new UserCredentials
        {
            email = "xxxx",
            password = "xxx"
        };

        try
        {
            var result = await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<UserCredentials, User>("Login", userCredentials);

            callback(result, null);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            callback(null, ex);
        }
```

Of course userCredentials is currently just for testing purpose there.
User class looks like this:

```
public class User
{

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public string UserID
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public string Email
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public string Token
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public string Status
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

I don't get any error but all properties of my user object are null, although they have values in the script(tested it with console logging)

Comment: How did they stop working? What error do you get?

Comment: Sry completely forgot to write about that edited question :)

Comment: Can you put some logging statements throughout your login script / token generation code and see where things become broken at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Somehow I changed the user properties to private set this was the problem